# Does the PS4 Pro have any features that the PS5 doesn't?

Tags: ps4, ps5

I've been considering getting a PS5 for a while now.  I currently have a PS4 Pro; if I end up getting a PS5, is there any reason to keep the PS4 Pro? Are there any features it includes which the PS5 doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are a few games that Sony has marked](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/games/ps5-backward-compatibility-games/)  for various reasons as "Only Playable on PS4". These games show up in the PS5 library but are unplayable. (The most infamous of these is the [P.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P.T._(video_game)) demo).

If you don't have any of those, I'm unaware of any feature reasons to keep the PS4 Pro.

> **PS4-only games**
>
> - Afro Samurai 2 Revenge of Kuma Volume One
> - Just Deal With It!
> - Robinson: The Journey
> - We Sing
> - Hitman Go: Definitive Edition
> - Shadwen
>
> This list is subject to change and excludes demos, media, and non-game
> applications.

Comment: Sony doesn't guarantee PS5-compatibility (but I'm not aware of issues): https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/games/ps5-backward-compatibility-games/